# Image not Accessible in Jinja2 used with django

Tags: jinja2

How to add images to HTML files using jinja2 templating tags? I tried to add css using `{% include %}` tag. But images are not being fetched.

views.py:

```
from django.template import loader, RequestContext 
from books.models import *
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from books.forms import *
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader, ChoiceLoader, PackageLoader, Template

env = Environment(loader=PackageLoader('mysite', 'templates',encoding='utf-8'))
def load(request):
    template = env.get_template('test.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(name='dd',current_date=datetime.datetime.now()))

def index(request):
    book_list = Book.objects.order_by('publication_date')[:5]
    t = env.get_template('index.html')
    return HttpResponse(t.render(book_list=book_list))
```

My Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Annai Book Shop</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
 content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
 <style>
 {% include "css/style.css" %}
 </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    {% include "js/jquery.flexslider-min.js" %}
    {% include "js/jquery.flexslider.js" %}
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function() {

    // more complex call
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
         animation: "slides",
         controlsContainer: ".flex-container",
         start: function(slider) {
           $('.total-slides').text(slider.count);
         },
         after: function(slider) {
           $('.current-slide').text(slider.currentSlide);
         }
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="page-out">
<div class="page-in">
<div class="page">
<div class="main">
<div class="header">
<div class="header-top">
<h1>Annai Book <span>Shop</span></h1>
</div>

<div class="header-bottom">
<div class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="images/slide-image-1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/slide-image-2.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/slide-image-3.jpg" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

No image is being fetched both in css and in img tag. Image is located in the current folder where the template is present.

Comment: Could you please show your template code and view?